# is there a way of targeting Firefox 3.6 and below using CSS?

Tags: css, firefox

I want to separately target Firefox 3.6 and below via CSS selectors without access to JS or server-side mechanisms. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: While googleing it, I came across this: http://css-tricks.com/2090-browser-detection-is-bad/ perhaps you can actually resolve the issue you are having in a standards compliant way?

Comment: I agree that capability testing is better.  However, what is worse is delivering your client something that does not look good, and this is strictly a layout issue, not a functionality issue.  If you know of a standards compliant method, please do let me know.  Note that I have no access to the HTML of the page I am styling, only a text box into which I can add my CSS. Thx.

Comment: You will have to resort to hacks, which are never good. Feature detection (note feature detection and not browser detection), is JavaScript territory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body:-moz-last-node #element {/* ≤ Firefox 3.6 */}
:-moz-any(html) #element {/* ≥ Firefox 4 */}
```

The second rule is there to reset recent versions of Gecko-based browsers.
But remember that it will probably be dropped in favour of [:matches()](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches) in the near future.